# Getting 'System.NullReferenceException' from driver.Url using Selenium IWebDriver in any class other than the Main function. C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a program that opens a browser from visual studio. It uses Selenium IWebDriver Firefox driver and when I use the same code from the Main method of the application it works just fine but when I use it anywhere else my driver's value is null even though I initialize the driver in that method.
I have tried Creating a driver and passing it to another class from program.cs Main method but it is of no use since I will be opening multiple forms within the application and It opens a new browser instance everytime. Here is the code below that returns null.
Thank you in advance.

```
public void browseracIVD()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //It just opens a blank browser and doesn't go to the URL
    driver.Url = "https://ivd.gib.gov.tr";

    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}
```

Comment: So the `driver.Url = ...` line throws a NullReferenceException?

Comment: @GregBurghardt When I debug it the driver itself shows null and driver.Url shows th exception. It doesnt throw the exceptionI just see a blank firefox browser. sorry if it was confusing on my part.

Comment: I'm still not understanding your question. So it is **not** throwing a NullReferenceException? Is the problem that the browser is showing a blank page?

Comment: Are you not looking for this `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://ivd.gib.gov.tr");`?

Comment: @Dumisani Hello, I have tried that as well It doesn't work since the driver is null.

Comment: Is the code you posted in your question the actual code that is failing?

Comment: @GregBurghardt It does not stop the application throwing the exception it just stays a blank browser but when i try to debug i see this: driver.Url = 'driver.Url' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' .(I dont see it throwing the exception on the line of that code i only see it when i debug though) Sorry for confusion

Comment: Ok. I see now. Hm. Very strange.

Comment: Which version of Firefox and FirefoxDriver are you using?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes. I create an instance of the class this method is in and i just call this method(don't know if this info helps) and yes my problem is the browser being blank. I don't quite understand how it can be null since I create it in the method. Oh and I have tried to create the driver out of the method in the class as well. Did not work

Comment: @GregBurghardt 73.0.1 (64-bit) firefox browser
0.26.0 Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver and I have other nuget packages like selenium.support etc too.

Comment: @Ezgi please paste the complete LOG to investigate it.

Comment: It sounds like something didn't get installed properly. I would remove the FF NuGet package and reinstall it and try again.

Comment: I have started a new thread and then called the method that opens the browser which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Started a new thread before calling the method which worked.